# Твои вещи? Подлежащее и сказуемое

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> Миша спросил: "Твои вещи?"

Где здесь подлежащее и сказуемое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Миша спросил: "Твои вещи?"***

Предложение с прямой речью, предикативная основа определяется для слов автора и для прямой речи.

***ТвоИ вещи?***

*Вещи* — подлежащее, *твои* — составное именное сказуемое, инверсия главных членов.

Прямой порядок слов: *Вещи твоИ?*

Comment: Получается, что и в основном части и в прямой речи есть по подлежащему и сказуемому?

Comment: Да, мы  имеем как бы сложное предложение, состоящее из двух частей, но  оформленное по особым правилам (с использованием кавычек и прописных букв). Такие предложения похожи на БСП.  К примеру, как и в БСП,  двоеточие обозначает  предупредительную паузу перед изъяснительной частью.

Comment: Ясно, Sharon, спасибо!

Comment: Можно ли считать, что опущено слово это (это твои вещи)? Возможна ли здесь двоякая интерпретация?

Comment: Это твои вещи? Семантика  мало изменилась, но грамматическая форма совсем другая. Я думаю, что опускать или подставлять ничего нельзя, анализ нужно проводить для заданного предложения.